# SuitescriptStruggling with outbound API call to 3rd party that uses CORS

Tags: javascript, c#, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am new to suitescript, and am working on customization projects in Netsuite for my company. I am wondering if anyone might possibly have any kind of reference, or specific code example that may help me with the road block I have found myself in. I am attempting to integrate DLS World Ship so we can be able to send the process shipment file, without having to copy/paste information into their ship software.

Unfortunately, the API call has to be done in backend code, as when it is sent from JAVASCRIPT, I get the cors error.

Here is the JS outbound API call I have:

```
var RateRequestViewModel = {
};

var jsonURL ="https://dlsworldwideproxy-dev.rrd.co...op/RateRequest";

$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  data:JSON.stringify(RateRequestViewModel),
  contentType:"application/json",
  url:jsonURL,
  beforeSend: function (request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("UserName", "Example Company Inc.");
    request.setRequestHeader('ApiKey',"insertAPIkeyher e"); 
  },
  success:function(data)
  {
  }
});
```

If anyone has any suggestions, or any kind of reference to get me out of this roadblock, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the examples for the N/https module. You can pretty easily make the server-side calls you need using that. In fact I believe if you use this module client side the request is proxied through Netsuite so CORS is not an issue there either.

briefly your code would look something like:

```
var headers = {
    "content-type" : 'application/json',
    "accept": 'application/json'
};

var response =  http.post({url:jsonURL, headers:headers, body:JSON.stringify(payload)}); // synchronous
```

or client side:

```
http.post.promise({url:jsonURL, headers:headers, body:JSON.stringify(payload)}).
    then(function(response){
        //handle the response
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Server-side javascript will not be able to use ajax.

You stated you needed to send a file but your example contentType is JSON. If it is just JSON you can use jQuery (do not use the $) for the ajax call from the browser. This would be done on the save function of a Client Script.

If you need to send the file you will need to create a SuiteScript script and deployment that is triggered via the afterSubmit. This will allow you to read the file contents and post it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I think that clears things up for me, at least a little bit. One thing I have been struggling with also, is creating the SuiteScript script/deployment either in C#, or how I can have it work with JS. I am having trouble finding any kind of C# references/guides, or any examples that would reflect sending the call-process file. Would you by chance be able to give an example, or a method in which I should think about going about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Everything in NetSuite is JavaScript. So I'm assuming if you're using C# you might be integrating from an external source. In that case, you can use webservices or REST.